# how do I get org cdimage updater to check for image updates more often?

Tags: argocd

argocd image updater is slowly polling the repository, how do I get org cdimage updater to check for image updates more often?
maybe there is some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution

argument

```
--interval 30s
```